# Stuck on cryptopals challenge 4 in Go

Tags: go, cryptography, nlp, xor

Problem: http://www.cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/4

I've previously completed this problem in C but I wanted to do a more generalised solution in Go (I just stopped checking strings for englishness when I reached one that matched my arbitrary goal in C, now I want the MOST english of all).

My solution works fine for the challenge 3 string, but when I try with challenge 4 I just get garbage out. More disconcertingly, I can't even see the correct string in the collection of strings generated by my XORs (I printed them all to a file). I've tried changing how I extract the strings from the text file (which is why I'm using a less standard method of getting the strings out) with no effect.

Challenge 3's string is "1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736" which should output "Cooking MC's like a pound of bacon" which functions correctly. Challenge 4 is a file with 300 odd lines, only one of which is the correct one to decode. It should decrypt to "Now that the party is jumping", but I just get "U+)Ex(unprintable)NSqhe/]PuSE7Nr;Rw;OUqeas". I've been able to get a couple of different outputs but never the correct one.

```
 func main() {
    filebytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("4.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    filestring := string(filebytes)
    lines := strings.Split(filestring, "\n")
    bestGuess := challenge4.GuessFile(lines)
    fmt.Println(bestGuess)
}

func GuessFile(lines []string) string {
    guessArray := make([]string, len(lines))
    for i, line := range lines {
        bytes, err := hex.DecodeString(line)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        guessArray[i] = challenge3.GuessString(bytes)
    }
    return utilities.MostEnglish(guessArray)
}


func GuessString(b []byte) string {
    guessArray := make([]string, 256)
    for i := 0; i < 256; i++ {
        guessArray[i] = string(utilities.SbXor(b, byte(i)))
    }
    return utilities.MostEnglish(guessArray)
}


    // MostEnglish takes a slice of strings and returns the string most likely to
// be an English sentence.
func MostEnglish(s []string) string {
    var maxVal uint64
    var maxStr string
    for _, line := range s {

        val := EnglishFreq(line)
        if val != 0 {

            if val > maxVal {
                maxVal, maxStr = val, line
            }
        }
    }
    return maxStr
}

// EnglishFreq takes a string and returns the  value representing
// the likelihood the string is a valid English sentence based on word frequency
    func EnglishFreq(s string) uint64 {
    var total uint64
    alphaFreq := map[rune]uint64{
        'A': 816,
        'B': 149,
        'C': 278,
        'D': 425,
        'E': 1270,
        'F': 222,
        'G': 201,
        'H': 609,
        'I': 696,
        'J': 15,
        'K': 77,
        'L': 402,
        'M': 240,
        'N': 674,
        'O': 750,
        'P': 192,
        'Q': 9,
        'R': 598,
        'S': 632,
        'T': 905,
        'U': 275,
        'V': 236,
        'W': 20,
        'X': 15,
        'Y': 197,
        'Z': 7,
    }

    for _, char := range s {
        if !unicode.IsPrint(char) {
            return 0
        }
        if val, ok := alphaFreq[unicode.ToUpper(char)]; ok {
            total += val
        }
    }
    return total
}
//SbXor does a single byte xor against a provided byte array
func SbXor(arr []byte, b byte) []byte {
    for i := range arr {
        arr[i] ^= b
    }
    return arr
}
```

Comment: What is the "challenge 3 string" or "challenge 4 string"? What is the output you're getting or the output you're expecting? What specifically is the issue you're having?

Comment: Challenge 3's string is "1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736" which should output "Cooking MC's like a pound of bacon" which functions correctly. Challenge 4 is a file with 300 odd lines, only one of which is the correct one to decode. It should decrypt to "Now that the party is jumping", but I just get "U+)Ex(unprintable)NSqhe/]PuSE7Nr;Rw;OUqeas". I've been able to get a couple of different outputs but never the correct one.

Comment: SbXor is never called in the quoted code. Is some relevant code missing?

Comment: Apologies, its been a long day already! I've added in the GuessString function after the GuessFile function, which calls SbXor.

Comment: So basically, one of the 60 character sequences in your input data (of 400 characters) will decode to an English sentence when decoded by xoring it's separate bytes with a fixed key?  And you want to use English character frequency to work out what this is?

Comment: Yes. I have used this method for challenge 3 with the single string and it works correctly for that. I have implemented previously in C and it works correctly there (albeit rather than doing all the iterations and then comparing them it checked each iteration and if that was satisfactory it returned early). The English character frequency is suggested by them as it comes in handy for later challenges.

Comment: For the record, I know challenge three explicitly mentions character frequency as a metric, but for challenges three and four, this is really overkill, since only one candidate is text at all! Just filtering out candidates that contain other characters than letters, spaces and apostrophe solves both challenges blazingly fast. For challenge four, unless I'm mistaken, only using character frequency is not enough anyway, because some of the garbage candidates have good English language statistics (maybe the problem seen in the OP).

Answer (score 0):

Your score function `EnglishFreq` is flawed. You ignore plaintext candidates that contain at least one non-printable character. However, there are some valid plaintexts that do contain one or more of those. For instance:

```
package main

import (
        "testing"
        "unicode"
)

func EnglishFreq(s string) uint64 {
        var total uint64
        alphaFreq := map[rune]uint64{
                'A': 816, 'B': 149, 'C': 278, 'D': 425, 'E': 1270, 'F': 222, 'G': 201,
                'H': 609, 'I': 696, 'J': 15, 'K': 77, 'L': 402, 'M': 240, 'N': 674,
                'O': 750, 'P': 192, 'Q': 9, 'R': 598, 'S': 632, 'T': 905, 'U': 275,
                'V': 236, 'W': 20, 'X': 15, 'Y': 197, 'Z': 7,
        }

        for _, char := range s {
                if !unicode.IsPrint(char) {
                        return 0
                }
                if val, ok := alphaFreq[unicode.ToUpper(char)]; ok {
                        total += val
                }
        }
        return total
}

func TestEnglishFreq(t *testing.T) {
        if s := "foo\nbar"; EnglishFreq(s) == 0 {
                t.Errorf("EnglishFreq(%q) == 0, want > 0", s)
        }
}

// $ go test
// --- FAIL: TestEnglishFreq (0.00s)
//     main_test.go:31: EnglishFreq("foo\nbar") == 0, want > 0
```

Don't discard potential plaintexts just because they contain a single unprintable character. Instead, reduce the score for each such character. This will be important in later challenges too.

I've had success with chi-squared testing, suggested in [an answer on Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/developing-algorithm-for-detecting-plain-text-via-frequency-analysis).